# How to make a button switch activities in an android app

Tags: android, button

I have a really beginner question about activities, I have just started a new project and I added a button. I would like to know how I can create a second activity (in eclipse) and THEN how do I link the first activity to the second with a button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To open another activity from an activity you should use [Intents](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html).

Tutorial from android doc: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html

Example:

```
//                  The context, The activity to open
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
// It will open the activity
startActivity(intent);
```

[`Intent constructor`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#Intent%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.Class%3C?%3E%29), [`startActivity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startActivity%28android.content.Intent%29)

It will open `NewActivity` activity, you should replace `NewActivity.class` with the Class name to open.

And remember you should add the Activity in the `AndroidManifest.xml`

---

Since you asked, to open an Activity at button click you need to use the [`OnClickListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html) of the Button, [`setOnClickListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnClickListener%28android.view.View.OnClickListener%29) will be used to set the listener.

```
// i get the reference to the button from the XML
Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
// now i set the listener
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
       // Here you should add the code you want to execute when the button is clicked
       // In our case we want to open the activity
       Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
       // It will open the activity
       startActivity(intent); 
       // ... and stop. 
    }
});
```

`new View.OnClickListener()` this line creates an anonymous class which implements interface `View.OnClickListener`... Read more [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) if you want to know.

Comment: Umm a little more description would help, like where do I put this, how do I link the button, how do I setup the onClick Listener. Sorry I just started programming android a few days ago

Comment: Ok, i will add how to open an activity at button click